# Boxplot for all my variables in SPSS

Tags: spss

I want to generate boxplots for all my variables (90 in total).

This is the syntax I would use for one variable:

`GGRAPH`
  `/GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=AnScol MISSING=LISTWISE`    `REPORTMISSING=NO`
  `/GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.`
`BEGIN GPL`
  `SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))`
  `DATA: AnScol =col(source(s), name("AnScol"))`
  `DATA: id=col(source(s), name("$CASENUM"), unit.category())`
  `COORD: rect(dim(1), transpose())`
  `GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("AnScol"))`
 `ELEMENT: schema(position(bin.quantile.letter(AnScol)), label(id))`
`END GPL`

How can I do that for all my variables without changing each variable one by one?

Thank you in advance!

Maxime M.

Comment: Normally you'd use a macro to do this, but macros don't work with GPL. So another way to go is with Python programmability - you can try this source: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ab16c38e-2f7b-4912-a47e-85682d124d32/entry/how_can_i_parameterize_ggraph_and_gpl_code6?lang=en .

Answer (score 0):

Here I will illustrate a few different ways. First, lets make some fake data - ten numeric variables and one string representing the Id variable for the dataset.

```
*Make fake data.
MATRIX.
SAVE {UNIFORM(100,10)} /VARS = V1 TO V10 /OUTFILE = *.
END MATRIX.
DATASET NAME Sim.
COMPUTE MyId = $casenum.
FORMATS MyId (F3.0).
ALTER TYPE MyId (A3).
```

A simple solution is to use `EXAMINE` to plot the box plot variable wise. This is available via the legacy dialogue type graphs.

```
*If the variables all have the same scale.
EXAMINE VARIABLES=V1 TO V10
  /COMPARE VARIABLE
  /PLOT=BOXPLOT
  /STATISTICS=NONE
  /NOTOTAL
  /ID=MyId
  /MISSING=LISTWISE.
```

[image]

This works fine since all the variables were constructed to be on the same scale. It has no outliers - but if there were they would be labelled with the `MyId` variable in the above plot.

You can also use `GGRAPH` to accomplish something very similar. Here I put outliers though, and in the `GGRAPH` code you cannot easily make an outlier variable.

```
*Make one variable not on the same scale and have outliers.
COMPUTE V1 = V1*100.
IF MyId = "  5" V1 = 250.
EXECUTE.
*Synonymous with GGRAPH - cant label outliers though.
GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=V1 TO V10
   TRANSFORM=VARSTOCASES(SUMMARY="V" INDEX="Vars")
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Vars=col(source(s), name("Vars"), unit.category())
  DATA: V=col(source(s), name("V"))
  ELEMENT: schema(position(bin.quantile.letter(Vars*V)))
END GPL.
```

[image]

You can see here because V1 is on a different scale now, you can't effectively visualize the other variables on one plot. In realistic datasets this is what will happen. To do individual plots, you can take eli-k's advice and use Python to submit different plots for each variable. Here is an example of that.

```
*If they don't - and you want different scales, Python programmability can do that.
BEGIN PROGRAM Python.
import spss, string

#get the variable list and the variable type
varList = [(spss.GetVariableName(i),spss.GetVariableType(i)) for i in range(spss.GetVariableCount())]

#make a template to submit boxplot, see https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/string-substitution-in-python-continued/ 
c = string.Template("""*Boxplots.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=$var MyId MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: V=col(source(s), name("$var"))
  DATA: MyId=col(source(s), name("MyId"), unit.category())
  COORD: rect(dim(1), transpose())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("$var"))
  ELEMENT: schema(position(bin.quantile.letter(V)), label(MyId))
END GPL.
""")

#loop over the varlist and plot if numeric
for i in varList:
  if i[1] == 0:
    spss.Submit(c.substitute(var=i[0]))
END PROGRAM.
```

And now you can see that each variable gets its own box plot to check quickly (and has the ID labeled).

[image]
[image]

etc. Finally, a way to accomplish something similar is to reshape all the numeric variables into one column, and then use `SPLIT FILE`.

```
*Varstocases and split file - need to know which variables are numeric to begin with.
VARSTOCASES /MAKE V FROM V1 TO V10 /INDEX VOrig.
SORT CASES BY VOrig.
SPLIT FILE BY VOrig.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=V MyId MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: V=col(source(s), name("V"))
  DATA: MyId=col(source(s), name("MyId"), unit.category())
  COORD: rect(dim(1), transpose())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("V"))
  ELEMENT: schema(position(bin.quantile.letter(V)), label(MyId))
END GPL.
SPLIT FILE OFF.
```